# Special matrix - don't know how

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, matrices, blkarray

Now... I know this code is embarrassing but it's the closer I've got, at least as displayed output, to what I'm trying to do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,blkarray,newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
 j\qquad\qquad\:\:\;\, \\
 i\,\left(
\begin{blockarray}{lrlr}
\begin{block}{lr|lr}
 a_{11} & \dots & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \quad & \quad & \vdots \\
\end{block}
\hline
\begin{block}{lr|lr}
\vdots & \quad & \quad & \vdots \\
 a_{n1} & \dots & \dots & a_{nn} \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\right) \\
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

The output is the following:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is basically what you see in the image above, but with a "a_{ij}" element in the middle instead of the cross.
Also the alignment of *i* and *j* is made using spaces, which I suppose is not the best solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Adding this as an additional answer. You could use the `multirow` package with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,newpxtext,newpxmath,multirow}
\begin{document}
\[
i\ \overset{\textstyle{j}}{\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & \multirow{2}{*}{\rule[-4ex]{.5pt}{5.5ex}} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots &  &  &  & \vdots\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\rule[.5 ex]{9ex}{.5pt}} & a_{ij} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rule[.5 ex]{9ex}{.5pt}} \\
\vdots &  & \multirow{2}{*}{\rule[-2ex]{.5pt}{5ex}} &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots &  & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{array}\right)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
\[
i\overset{\textstyle{j}}{\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots &  & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
 & \cdots & a_{ij} & \cdots & \\
\vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots &  & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}}
\]
```

[image]

You could remove the additional `\vdots` and `\cdots` commands if you like. Or add some `\ddots` for diagonals.

Comment: This solves the _i_ and _j_ alignment problem, but I also need the straight lines instead of dots. Sorry if I didn't made myself clear, and thanks for your help

Comment: I provided an additional answer with the lines.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution with `booktabs`, a `pmatrix` environment and one more column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, blkarray, newpxtext, newpxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{aligned}
    \MoveEqLeft[4.6]\scriptstyle j \\[-0.5ex]
    \raisebox{0.4ex}{$\scriptstyle i $~}\begin{pmatrix}
      \!\!\begin{blockarray}{lr@{}c@{}lr}
        \begin{block}{c@{\enspace}c@{}c@{}c@{\enspace}c}
          a_{11} & ... & \vrule & ... & a_{1n} \\
            ⋮ & \quad &\vrule & \quad & ⋮ \\
        \end{block}
        & & a_{ij} & & \\[-1.5ex]
        \cmidrule[0.4pt](l){1-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](r){4-5}\addlinespace[0.6ex]
        \begin{block}{c@{\enspace}c@{}c@{}c@{\enspace}c}
            ⋮ & \quad & \vrule & \quad & ⋮ \\
          a_{n1} & ... & \vrule & ... & a_{nn}\\[-1.6ex]
        \end{block}
      \end{blockarray}\!\!
      %\right) \\
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{aligned} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, now this is exactly what I want! Although I'm having some problems with the `newpx`package (which I've just installed), when I compile it gives me `! LaTeX Error: File 'binhex.tex' not found.` <\br> Any idea what is the problem here and how to solve?

Comment: @CAKES - Which TeX distribution (and which vintage) is installed on your system?

Comment: @Mico - I'm using MacTeX and... what's a _vintage_? (Sorry if I'm such a newbie)

Comment: Mico means ‘which year?’.

Comment: @CAKES - Is it MacTeX2017, MacTeX2016, MacTeX2009, etc? Did you do a full or just a "minimal" installation of MacTeX?

Comment: It's MacTeX2016 and I did a full installation (it has TexShop, LaTeXiT, Excalibur and TeX Live Utility)

Comment: @CAKES - Is there something stopping you from updating to MacTeX2017?  By the way, if you can't get the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages to run correctly, try switching to the `mathpazo` package -- or any other font package that provides both text and math fonts...

Comment: @Mico - I have MacOS 10.9 and MacTeX2017 requires 10.10.   I tried with `mathpazo`an still get a similar error: `! I can't find file 'pplr7t'`. Are these problems about my distribution? I'm downloading packages from 2016, I'd really like to understand what's the problem...

Comment: @CAKES - It sounds very much like you've pursued some minimal installation of MacTeX, i.e., one that loads very few LaTeX packages. Is this right? If so, why?

Comment: @Mico - I'm sorry but I'm not sure about this... I've downloaded it from [http://www.tug.org/mactex/](http://www.tug.org/mactex/). Are you telling me I should reinstall everything?

Comment: @CAKES - On that link you provided: Did you go with the full MacTeX distribution, or did you choose BasicTeX?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66254/discussion-between-cakes-and-mico).

Comment: @Mico - No, I'm pretty sure I downloaded the full MacTeX distribution (is there a way to see it from my computer? Just to be sure)

Comment: @CAKES - The fact that MacTeX can't find certain font files is an indication that a less-than-complete distribution was installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `blkarray`; the only needed tricks are `\BAmulticolumn` and a definition for a filling rule higher than `\hrulefill`.

I defined the height the same as the fraction bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,blkarray,newpxtext,newpxmath}

\newcommand{\highhrulefill}{%
  \leavevmode
  \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
                 depth  \dimexpr-\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
  \hfill
  \kern 0pt
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{blockarray}{ccc|cc}
&& \BAmulticolumn{2}{c}{j} \\
\begin{block}{c(cc|cc)}
& a_{11} & \cdots & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
& \vdots &       &       & \vdots \\
i & \BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\highhrulefill \; a_{ij} \; \highhrulefill} \\
& \vdots &       &       & \vdots \\
& a_{n1} & \cdots & \cdots & a_{nn} \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]